# How can I explain that working here has been my dream since forever

Tags: resume, applications, work-experience

I am currently looking for my first job, after a six months internship. And I found a job offer from a great company (and my dream company) that says having an experience is optional.  I was planing on trying to get there later when I have enough experience and a tight resume. Is it a good idea to try and get there now? It won’t affect my chances later?

And more importantly is it okay to explain in my application that this is my dream job and that I have a lot of respect for this company's work? If so how do you think I should put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not believe that it is okay for you to put on your application that it is your *dream job*.

It is great that you are enthusiastic about the opportunity and a better way to demonstrate that enthusiasm would be to state on the application how much you have contributed to the company so far during your short internship. Explain that you have what it takes to do the job and substantiate this statement with concrete facts from your internship and possibly other experiences.

Finally, you should only join company you have respect for. If not, you are not going to be happy in the long run. Explaining on your application that you have respect for the company will not help you one iota.

However, I must admit that your question was very joyful and made me want to know more and possible work for you. I am guessing that expressing informally that it is your dream job would help, I simply would not put it on the application which is more a formal process and you are not sure who will read the application.

Comment: I will say "dream job" is a bit much for an application or interview. But most applications and interviews will ask "Why do you want to work here?" (Very good question)  in those cases as long as the person is enthusiastic about stuff that makes sense  it's beneficial to their cause. Be it company culture, the type of work, the market, etc. As someone hires people those are all good in my book. It's when someone just puts "because you pay more" or something pretty neutral that I lose interest in that person. (You want me to want to hire you, I want you to want to work for me)

Comment: I agree that dream job is a bit much. In that context, I agree that explaining what the company is doing and how you like the culture may be useful. I guess we read the question slightly differently. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I ended up saying that I had much respect for the company's work and I'de like to have a part in it. I didn't really get what you wanted to say by the last part of your answer.

Comment: @Ayu I think it means in writing it is a more formal setting so you can't say the phrase "It's my dream job" because its too informal, but suppose you're talking to the inteviewer and things seem a bit informal, then in some circumstance you could use that phrase verbally to express your enthusiasm/passion. However you have to read the interviewer and situation to know what level of communication is appropriate. e.g. if more formality is expected in speaking

Answer (score 3):

If Experience is optional and you feel capable of doing what is required, then now is a perfectly good time. (sure more experience is a plus, but they've said it's no problem)

Applying for a job even if you don't get it is never a deal breaker for getting a job with that company later. (unless you fail your drug test or behave in a manner that would put you on a "do not hire" list) The only thing is if you're turned down let a little time pass before applying again. (It's good to show people you still want to work for them, it's not good to seem obsessed.)

It's also not a bad thing to say "I've wanted to work here since , because " just make sure to keep it professional and not creep into the creepy fandom or obsessed territory.

Basically "I have wanted to work for  ever since I heard you guys dedicate 15% of employee time to employee self improvement a few years ago. I invest a great deal of time and ambition into self improvement and would love to work for a company that supports this ambition." As apposed to *breathing heavily* "I NEED to work for you guys!!! 15% time for self improvement? Yes, please, and thank you! YOU NEED to hire me or I'll just die!" *gives a anxious stare towards the interviewer's clipboard*

Comment: your answer is interesting. As you can see by mine, I take a very different approach. As an hiring manager, I am more interested in what a candidate can do for me rather than what the company can do for them. The latter is important but not necessarily as part of the application process.

Comment: @RualStorge I would say that it is "USUALLY" not a deal breaker in the future to interview and not get a job.  I worked at one employer where this was an issue and if you didn't do well the first time around they weren't likely to hire you - EVER.  I'm not saying that it's right (sounds crazy to me), but there are those out there (FYI, this is a large tech company in Texas).

Comment: @Jared probably true. If I interviewed you and you lacked exp (the case here) and you came back 2 - 3 years later, we're in good shape as you gained what you lacked. If you interviewed and you came off as abrasive though... Do not hire list. But yeah, Usually is probably more accurate.